# Identifying Min and Max values of a property on a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net

I have this class

```
class TimeSeriesDataPoint
{
    public int HistorianID { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public int Quality { get; set; }
}
```

and an array of lists of objects of this class

```
List<TimeSeriesDataPoint>[] Curves = new List<TimeSeriesDataPoint>[numberOfCurves];
```

Each Curve has a list of around 1000 of TimeSeriesDataPoint objects. I need to identify for each Curve (Curves[0], Curves[1], etc) the min and max for the property "Value".

Can I use the Min and Max Method present in the List class? Can someone help me on that?

Renan

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach (var curve in Curves)
{
    double min = curve.Min(x => x.Value);
    double max = curve.Max(x => x.Value);
    // do something with your min, max, and curve
}
```

If performance is an issue, you can calculate the min and max values in one pass if you implement it yourself. You can use [Mono's implementation](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs) of the `Min` and `Max` methods as a starting point.

Comment: this only gets you the max across all.  he wants the maxes of *each* curve, if I read it correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `Min()` and `Max()` extension methods:

```
var results = Curves.Select(c => new { Min=c.Min(t => t.Value), Max=c.Max(t => t.Value) });
```

This will give you, for each curve, the min and max.  However, it's going to enumerate each set twice (once for min, and once for max).

Answer (score 2):

```
var maxEachCurve = Curves.Select( curve => curve.Max( x => x.Value ) );
var minEachCurve = Curves.Select( curve => curve.Min( x => x.Value ) );
```

`maxEachCurve`, `minEach` curve is now an `IEnumerable<double>` where each element is the max/min for that curve

or to do it in one pass:

```
var minMaxEachCurve = Curves.Select( 
    curve => new Tuple<double,double>(
        curve.Min( x=> x.Value), 
        curve.Max( x => x.Value ) ));
```

minMaxEachCurve is now an `IEnumerable<Tuple<double,double>>` where each element is a pair of min/max values